# AWS: How to check that credentials are correct?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

The following function (in Javascript) is supposed to accept accessKey and secretKey and check whether they are correct:

```
function checkKeys(accessKey, secretKey) {
    var cred = new AWS.Credentials(accessKey, secretKey, null);
    cred.get(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR!")
        } else {
            console.log("Keys are OK")
        }
    })
}
```

I'd expect that get() method returns an error in case of incorrect credentials. I don't know why, but it doesn't matter what credentials I give, I never get an error, and console always prints "Keys are OK".

Comment: A check like this doesn't provide any value. See my answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38902497/1428388

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really check that credentials are "correct". Think about user roles. User may be authorized to make one API call, but not another. The only generic thing you can do is make sure that ID+key pair you have are valid AWS credentials with `STS.getCallerIdentity()` (see [SDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/STS.html#getCallerIdentity-property) for details). Note that it will return caller details even if this caller has no access to any of the services, so take the results with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

You're just storing credentials in a local object, and then retrieving them. You need to trigger an actual AWS API call in order to verify if the credentials are valid.

Comment: so the only way to check it is actually trying to make a query. right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "query". The only way to check is to actually do *something* with the SDK that causes it to hit the AWS API. You tagged the question with S3 for some reason, so maybe a call to S3 to check if an object exists.